# How to multiply two numbers supplied as command line arguments in C

Tags: c, argv, argc

I am trying to find the multiple of two numbers supplied as arguments in the command line using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * main - Entry point for my program
 * @argc: This is the number of arguments
 * @argv: This is the array of arguments
 *
 * Return: Zero upon program success
 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i;

        int result = 1;

        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
                result = result * argv[i];
        }
        printf("%d\n", result);
        return (0);
}
```

But as  I try to compile my code, I get the following error:

```
3-mul.c: In function ‘main’:
3-mul.c:19:19: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int’ and ‘char *’)
   19 |   result = result * argv[i];
      |                   ^ ~~~~~~~
      |                         |
      |                         char *
```

How do I get around this error?

Comment: You need to convert the *string* to an integer. I suggest `strtol(argv[i], 0, 10)`, or, even better, use the 2nd argument to test for errors. link to [POSIX strtol() man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html)

Comment: You need to convert the argument strings into numbers, probably by use `strtol()` or some similar function (`strtod()`, `strtoimax()`, etc).

Comment: Unrelated - but you've potentially made two mistakes that luckily cancel out. 1: argv[0] (the first element) is the name of the program. You don't want this in your multiplication. 2: Arrays in C start at 0. In this case, you want to start at argv[1], but for future reference, _that is not the first element of the array_

Comment: Your title says "numbers".  Do you want to only work with integers (as indicated by the fact that your `result` variable is of type `int`), or do you actually want to work with non-integer values?  Do you care about "large" numbers (eg, outside the range of `int` or `double`)?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
result = result * argv[i];
```

will not work, because `argv[i]` is not an integer, but it is of type `char *`, i.e. a pointer to a string. It does not make sense to multiply an integer with a pointer.

What you want to do is to convert the string pointed to by `argv[1]` to an integer, and then multiply that integer with `result`. A simple way to do this would be to use the standard library function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), by changing the line

```
result = result * argv[i];
```

to

```
result = result * strtol( argv[i], NULL, 10 );
```

and by adding `#include <stdlib.h>` to the start of the file.

If the conversion fails, then the function `strtol` will simply return `0`, causing your final result to also be `0`. Also, if the user enters a number that is so large that it is not representable as a `long`, then the function `strtol` will simply return the largest representable number. If that is not what you want, then you probably want to print an error message instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    long result = 1;

    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        long num;
        char *p;

        //attempt to convert argv[i] to integer
        errno = 0;
        num = strtol( argv[i], &p, 10 );

        //verify that conversion was successful
        if ( p == argv[i] )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Conversion of argv[%d] failed!\n", i );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //check for range error
        if ( errno == ERANGE )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Argument of argv[%d] out of range!\n", i );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //conversion was successful and the range was ok, so we
        //can now use the converted number
        result = result * num;
    }

    //print the sum
    printf( "%ld\n", result );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For the command-line arguments

```
3 abc
```

this program has the following output:

```
Conversion of argv[2] failed!
```

For the command-line arguments

```
3 500000000000000000000
```

this program has the following output:

```
Argument of argv[2] out of range!
```

For the command-line arguments

```
3 5
```

this program has the following output:

```
15
```

For the command-line arguments

```
3 5abc
```

this program has the following output:

```
15
```

This program is still not perfect, though, because, as shown above, it is accepting the command-line argument `5abc` as a valid representation for the number `5`. If you want that argument to be rejected too, then the program would have to perform further validation tests.